# Ruby - Unknown method init

Tags: ruby, user-interface, gtk3

I learn some ruby and today I tried to started with gtk3 to build a GUI.
I found this tutorial

http://zetcode.com/gui/rubygtk/introduction/

And I copy the code an tried to run the script in my terminal with.

```
sudo ruby gui.rb
```

But I get only this error code.

> gui.rb:34:in `<main>': undefined method`init' for Gtk:Module (NoMethodError)

I have installed the gtk3 gem with the following command.

```
sudo gem install gtk3
```

Before I tried to use the gtk with ..

```
sudo gem install gtk2
```

Where is the error ?
I have installed successfully gtk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use the `GTK.init` method anymore.

---

From the tutorial you are following just keep the code as bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

'''
ZetCode Ruby GTK tutorial

This program centers a window on 
the screen.

Author: Jan Bodnar
Website: www.zetcode.com
Last modified: May 2014
'''

require 'gtk3'

class RubyApp < Gtk::Window

    def initialize
        super

        set_title "Center"
        signal_connect "destroy" do 
            Gtk.main_quit 
        end

        set_default_size 300, 200

        set_window_position Gtk::Window::Position::CENTER

        show
    end
end

# Gtk.init
    window = RubyApp.new
Gtk.main
```

---

Also, you shouldn't use sudo to install your gems, so you can run your script without being root.
Running `sudo gem` will install your gems into your root home.

Comment: I will update my tutorial when Debian updates its Ruby GTK packages. It still uses an older package where the init works.
Also, I am not user about your last statement.

Comment: By my last statement you mean `Gtk.main` ?

Comment: No, this one: Running sudo gem will install your gems into your root home. For what I know, this is not correct.

Comment: I haven't really made a deep investigation about that. Feel free to correct me :) .

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you didn't define the method you're trying to run on line 34 of your program..

If you're trying to do something with GUI in Ruby, I'd suggest using Shoes instead, Shoes is very simple and there's a lot of great tutorials out there.

Here's a link to Shoes: http://shoesrb.com/

Comment: Thank's for your hint, but I think the the 'init' method come's from gtk3 .
And I have required it with 'require 'gtk3' and i get the error.

Comment: Line 34 has a method that's undefined, either way as long as that method stays undefined you could require 'god' and it wouldn't make a difference. If you would really like somebody to be able to answer your question I'd suggest you post your source code so we can actually find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm debugging similar problems at the moment with older code.  The 3.0.x series of the gtk gem has (a) no `init` method and (b) no up-to-date documentation I can find,... :-(

To go back to the version of `gtk3` that works with that code try

```
gem install gtk --version "~> 2.2"
```

or use `~> 2.2` in your gemspec if you are using one